# Is it just me or does this look bad?

Tags: discussion, user-experience

I feel that the outlined text should be consistent in size and color with that below it.

The outlined text is;

```
color: #c8ccd0;
font-size: 18px;
```

Whereas that below it is;

```
color: #9199a1;
font-size: 13px;
```

[image]

Is there a reason why this is the case and do you feel it's worth changing?

Comment: Without even checking I can tell you that the color contrast probably isn't WCAG compliant, but just saying "it looks bad" is not likely to get a very good reception here. I'd suggest adding a little more detail.

Comment: Yes it looks bad. It should have been a red circle.

Comment: Well, Windows 7 got away with lowering the contrast to the point of being unusable (together with other detrimental changes to usability).

Comment: The color is questionable. The rest seems ok IMO

Comment: At best, the color, yes. In the other case, the size emphasizes the contrast between period and date, i.e. newer events remain highlighted.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Windows 7 was the best-usable Windows I can remember. I'm not sure that had much to do with contrast, but... it's a bit ridiculous to claim that everything must have well-readable contrast. That `1d` field contains almost no information, it's _good_ to sink something like that almost completely into the background. On the opposite side, I find something like Windows 10's EVERYTHING FULL IN YOUR FACE menu over-saturated to the point on unusability. (Disclosure: I have hardly used any Windows for ~10 years, as I much prefer Xfce where I can set my contrasts as low as I like.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm going to make an assumption that you aren't visually impaired? According to gov.uk - _"Around 1 in 12* men and 1 in 200* women have some degree of colour vision deficiency."_ That's a _lot_ of people. Having bigger differences in contrast is for them, not for you or for aesthetics. **Note** I apologise if the above assumption is untrue.

Comment: @Lewis I appreciate the point. _Public information screens_ should most definitely use high contrast. However, enforcing this upon all users of a website doesn't make sense, like it doesn't make sense to enforce wheelchairs upon all people. The correct approach is to offer an alternative CSS for visually impaired people. (Indeed, I'd argue there should always be _multiple_ styles available, one for normal-sighted people, one for colour-impaired, one for sharpness-impaired, etc..)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I hear you. However, I guess for us that's a viable alternative - but double the development effort for SO. A one-size-fits-all (we don't have trouble seeing it either way) is the most _economic_ option in almost all cases.

Comment: @Lewis it's not _double_ the effort, it's just a couple of lines of extra CSS. I myself maintain alternative style sheets for ≈20 websites, just because I don't like their design. Clearly that isn't something most people would do, but it's something every major website _should offer_ IMO. (Again something Microsoft did right here: e.g. the Teams webapp does offer a standard, a dark, and a high-contrast style.)

Comment: It might be a few lines of extra CSS, but double testing for every new feature. I understand your point, though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it's certainly much more than a couple of lines of extra CSS. For a site like SO, to have a thematically sound high contrast style option would be likely over a thousand lines.

Comment: @TylerH: No doubt.  Which is probably 5% of the total CSS, and .1% of the site source code.  leftroundabout is correct that it would not be anywhere near doubling the development or maintenance effort of the site.

Answer (score 10):

Yep, seems fairly inconsistent in a few places. A couple of touch ups *could* help;

1. Actions could have the same blue text / grey background
2. Dates / time could look more consistent
3. Hopefully the two different blues in the titles are down to :visited styles
4. The bottom title really bothers me. Not sure why though.

*- <sup>Poor photoshop skills included for free.</sup>

[image]

Comment: *The bottom title really bothers me.* You mean the "Return from the recursive function once"? I think it's that it doesn't look like a link at all. Maybe the question was deleted?

Comment: @BSMP Yep, good shout.

Comment: You can see examples on the OP's [all actions activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2926779/madison-courto?tab=activity&sort=all). The post isn't deleted, the colouring of the links is just all over the place, the grey ones even go light blue when active and then dark blue once visited.